# Is there a way to dissolve faces automatically filling the gaps with new faces?

Tags: modeling

When I dissolve faces, it leaves a hole in my mesh, like this:

[image]

[image]

If I want to fill the gaps now, I select the edges and hit `F`.

[image]

Is there any way to dissolve faces automatically filling gaps, so I don't have to do it manually?